# Copy .parquet file with dates from S3 to Redshift

Tags: date, copy, amazon-redshift, parquet

I am trying to load a .parquet file with COPY command from S3 into my Redshift database.

The file contains a column with dates in format 2018-10-28. The related field in the table in Redshift is defined as date. The source spark dataframe shows the field as datetime64 and converted to pandas it is timestamp.

Using a simple `COPY dates FROM s3://mybucket/file.parquet iam_role {xxxxx} FORMAT AS PARQUET` always returns an incompatible schema error.

In my jupyter notebook i cannot see the complete error description, but would guess  it is the date field as the rest of the table a simple varchar field and some int fields

Is there a way to see the complete error message, as it is not written to stl_load_errors?

Is there a better source format than yyyy-mm-dd for loading the data to redshift?

Comment: try setting up a target table with strings instead of dates

Comment: Yes, query table `svl_s3log` . The error message spits out the pid. You can filter by that and find the error on column `message`.

Answer (score 2):

Redshift and parquet format don't get along most of the time.

You have couple of options, the top two among them are

1. Use a Glue crawler to create the table in Glue Data Catalog and use it from Redshift as an external (Spectrum) table, you need to do this once. Your COPY becomes INSERT.
2. Load the file into a table with every single column (or you date columns) defined as varchar, transform as a second pass.

If data is not going to change in Redshift you can keep them in S3 (becomes a data lake) and using method 1 above you can read it from Redshift.

I have a use case just worked on last week to bring an S3 data set in parquet format to Redshift and used the first method above and kept the data in S3.

Let me know if you have any further questions. I'll be glad to help.

Comment: Hi @demircioglu can you please elaborate a bit further (more like a step by step) on how to do number 1? I urgently need to get this step done. Please help if you are reading this now. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Something the like (not tested):

```
 COPY dates FROM s3://mybucket/file.parquet iam_role {xxxxx} DATEFORMAT yyyy-mm-dd FORMAT AS PARQUET
```

[Redshift documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEFORMAT_and_TIMEFORMAT_strings.html)

Comment: Your solution produces this error -
`DATEFORMAT argument is not supported for PARQUET based COPY [SQL State=0A000]`